# How to fix '29/19/93_' incorrect date with '2/9/1993'

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

Having a problem with custom mat-datepicker. The date is being loaded into the front-end in an incorrect format and should read as 'MM/DD/YYYY'

For example 4/1/1993 is coming through as this: '29/19/93__'
The data is coming into front-end as ISO format which we want to display in 'MM/DD/YYYY' format

The conversion is not working on loaded input data, however upon clicking into the input text box the date is appearing with correct format

On load with incorrect date format:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iilq.jpg

After clicking in the input text box
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dhfS.jpg

We have tried looking at the change events occur when the dateValue is created and when click events occur on the text box

**HTML**

```
<input (dateChange)="inputEvent($event, 'text')" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker"
         [value]="dateValue"
         [min]="minDate"
         [max]="maxDate"
         [style.width]="inputWidth"
         class="form-control"
         [textMask]="{mask:dateInputMask}"
         [placeholder]="placeholder">
```

**TS**

```
dateInputMask = [/\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, '/', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];

 inputEvent(event: any, source: string) {
    // if full date entered convert to moment and set dateValue to moment

    this.dateValue = event.target.value;

    if (this.dateValue !== null && !this.dateValue.isValid()) {
      this.dateValue = null;
    }
  }

writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value === null) {
      this.dateValue = null;
      return;
    }
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.dateValue = moment(value, this.inFormat);
      if (this.dateValue == null) {
        this.dateValue = moment(value, this.format);
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Not an expert by any means but

looking at [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/datepicker-input.ts) there is a `_onBlur()` event which formats the date:

 `_formatValue` → `_dateAdapter.format`

where `_dateAdapter` comes from `@Optional() private _dateAdapter: DateAdapter<D>` in [datepicker.ts](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/datepicker.ts)
and `DateAdapter` is an import from `'@angular/material/core';`

Answer (score 1):

### Choosing a date implementation and date format settings

The datepicker was built to be date implementation agnostic. This means that it can be made to work with a variety of different date implementations. However it also means that developers need to make sure to provide the appropriate pieces for the datepicker to work with their chosen implementation.

...

### Customizing the parse and display formats

The MAT_DATE_FORMATS object is just a collection of formats that the datepicker uses when parsing and displaying dates. These formats are passed through to the DateAdapter so you will want to make sure that the format objects you're using are compatible with the DateAdapter used in your app.

...

Ref: [Choosing a date implementation and date format settings](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings)

Additional Resources:

- [Taking Advantage of the Angular Material Datepicker](https://blog.angular.io/taking-advantage-of-the-angular-material-datepicker-237e80fa14b3)
- [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/)